# GPU not being used in GPU-based Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure-container-instances

I'm trying to get `bert-as-a-service` running on GPU-backed Azure Container Instance. Unfortunately even though I've got this running on a K80 SKU, bert-as-a-service still falls back to CPU instead of leveraging the GPU.

If you look at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile) for bert-as-a-service you can see that it uses the `tensorflow:1.12.0-gpu-py3` base image.

I can use Tensorflow to see that the GPU device is available in the container, e.g. `sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))` prints the appropriate GPU information corresponding to the K80 SKU.

However I noticed that `bert-as-a-service` uses `GPUtil` which uses `nvidia-smi` to determine GPU devices, and `nvidia-smi` doesn't exist in the container. If I run `GPUtil.getGPUs()` in the container, I get nothing.

`bert-as-a-service` [suggests to add the `runtime=nvidia` flag](https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service#2-start-the-bert-service) to the `docker run` command but I thought if I have the K80 SKU this should be running on the docker nvidia runtime.

Is there a way to get `bert-as-a-service` to identify the GPU? And why doesn't `nvidia-smi` exist in the K80 SKU?

Comment: Can you share the image?

Comment: @CharlesXu I'd be happy to share the docker image, but it is large. You can build it yourself with that Dockerfile:

1. Download/unzip the file here: https://storage.googleapis.com/bert_models/2018_10_18/uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12.zip

2. `docker build -t bert-as-service -f ./docker/Dockerfile . &&
PATH=/PATH_TO/_YOUR_MODEL/ &&
docker run --runtime nvidia -dit -p 5555:5555 -p 5556:5556 -v $PATH:/model -t bert-as-service 1`

These instructions are on: https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service

If you prefer just the image, let me know where you prefer I upload this file to (it's 3.5GB)